# Mobile Broadband disappears

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband

I found some pretty old discussions about this problem, but any hacks proposed there didn't work, so forgive me for asking this again.

I have a Thinkpad X250 and a X1 Yoga 1st gen, both with WWAN cards. I have the exact same problem with both: the mobile broadband settings disappear from the network settings. Sometimes after boot I can enable the interface and even get some data moving, but after a while the setting disappears from the Network settings. Like so:
[image: Missing mobile broadband settings]

I'm using Groovy right now.

Comment: Hey Rampant, looking your question language I guess you are not noob so i think i don't need to explain steps. Can you try making your connection with. `nm-connection-editor`. Just type it in terminal and try.  Hope this helps :))

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it didn't work. I recorded a short video from what happens. This is from a fresh 20.04 install on my X250. The [video](https://youtu.be/PkqQh4JSoQ0) Hw-probe [before](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=c4b4e94df8&log=iwconfig) and [after](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=c4b4e94df8&log=iwconfig) disappearance. There's something interesting in the iwconfig log, the row `wwan0     no wireless extensions` disappears as the mobile broadband dies.

Comment: @preIdiot Rampant forgot to ping you!